# Processing js jump system

Tags: javascript, processing, processing.js

I`m trying to make a jump system in processing.js and its done, but not quite what I wanted. The thing is that like this, the jump height depends on how long the key is pressed. What I wanted is the same height regardless how long the key is pressed.

Here is my code:

```
var keys = [];
void keyPressed() {
    keys[keyCode] = true;
};
void keyReleased() {
    keys[keyCode] = false;
};

var Player = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.g = 0;
    this.vel = 2;
    this.jumpForce = 7;
    this.jump = false;
};
Player.prototype.draw = function() {
    fill(255,0,0);
    noStroke();
    rect(this.x, this.y, 20, 20);
};
Player.prototype.move = function() {
    if(this.y < ground.y) {
        this.y += this.g;
        this.g += 0.5;
        this.jump = false;
    }
    if(keys[RIGHT]) {
        this.x += this.vel;
    }
    if(keys[LEFT]) {
        this.x -= this.vel;
    }

    //preparing to jump
    if(keys[UP] && !this.jump) {
        this.jump = true;
    }
    // if jump is true, than the ball jumps... after, the gravity takes place pulling the ball down...
    if(this.jump) {
        this.y -= this.jumpForce;
    }
};
Player.prototype.checkHits = function() {
    if(this.y+20 > ground.y) {
        this.g = 0;
        this.y = ground.y-20;
        jump = false;
    }
};

Var Ground = function(x, y, label) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;this.label = label;
};
Ground.prototype.draw = function() {
    fill(0);
    rect(0, 580, width, 20);
};

var player = new Player(width/2, height/2);
var ground = new Ground(0, 580, "g");
void draw() {
    background(255,255,255);
    player.draw();
    player.move();
    player.checkHits();
    ground.draw();
}
```

Any help would be aprreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing here is like: "If this(the Player) isn't touching the ground then, if (in addition) key UP is pressed, jump!". So it will allow the player jumping even if he is in the air... increasing the jump height

You should do something like: "if player is touching the ground allow to jump (if key UP pressed), otherwise you are already jumping!".

Something like this:

```
if(this.y < ground.y) {
    this.y += this.g;
    this.g += 0.5;
    this.jump = true;
}
else{
    this.jump = false;
}

if(keys[UP] && !this.jump) {
    this.jump = true;
    this.y -= this.jumpForce;
}
```

Comment: thank you =) i dont know what i did wrong but i remade the code and it works. i don't think it was the jump true or false but thanks anyway =)